# How to convert unix timestamp to formatted date in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date

I'm struggling with ruby date api. I need to convert a timestamp number to formatted date. But when i use:

```
Time.at(1517486994710).to_datetime
```

or

```
DateTime.strptime("1517486994710",'%s')
```

(1517486994710 is unix timestamp for today), i see 50057 year as output. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

You have the epoch *with milliseconds*. Use `%Q` formatter:

```
DateTime.strptime("1517486994710",'%Q')
#⇒ Thu, 01 Feb 2018 12:09:54 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks! But in this case time is truncated(as you can see)... Is there any solutions for it?

Comment: Oh geez, please excuse me I messed the formatters; it’s definitely `%Q`.

Answer (score 3):

Your script is correct but your epoch is incorrect. Today epoch is 1517491785.
You probably got the js epoch which counts in milliseconds

```
DateTime.strptime("1517486994",'%s')  # removed 710
```

Comment: It's time generated from java side. So is there any formatter for this case? Or just truncate the num?

Comment: truncate or divide the epoch by 1000 would suffice

Comment: This is a wrong approach to giving pieces of advice. The question is not how to fix the world around, the question is how to live in. Check my answer for the correct answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa most system use epoch in seconds anyway, i don't see the harm in standardizing the value. It would be much easier to manipulate in ruby and if you divide the value by 1000 you still keep the precision anyway

Comment: The rule of thumb is: don’t change the format while passing data between subsystems back and forth. Also, your opinion on “most systems use epoch in seconds” is a bit obsolete :)